# Java Socket with Socks4 proxy change to Socks5

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, socks

I want to change socket proxy type from socks4 to socks5. This is what I tried on Socket with socks4 already set.

```
public static void setSocks5Version(Socket socket){

    try {
        Method m = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getImpl");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object sd = m.invoke(socket);
        m = sd.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setV4");
        m.setAccessible(false);

        socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getImpl").setAccessible(false);
    } catch (Throwable var16) {
        var16.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to set socks proxy to v5!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

And it failed with no error.

Comment: Please show the stack of the error you get.

Comment: can you try printing var16 in catch block. it should give you more details about where it is failing with reason

Comment: *"Failed with no error"*? 

Comment: Why don't you just create it with socks5 mode to start with?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Method m = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getImpl");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object sd = m.invoke(socket);
        sd.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setV4").setAccessible(false);
        m.setAccessible(false);
```

This solved my problem.